# CORS is blocking PUT, DELETE, and POST requests but GET is working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I am at a loss. I am trying to configure `CORS` and I have tried just about everything I can find on the internet/Stack overflow.

Requests are working in Postman but not in React using axios.

Here is my function for deleting a user (this works in `Postman` but not when triggered in React):

```
 deleteEmployeeById(id) {
    // return axios.delete(API_BASE_URL + `employees/${id}`);
    var testing = "";
    return axios
      .delete(API_BASE_URL + `employees/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${HARDCODED_JWT_TESTING}`,
        },
      })
      .then("yessssss")
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("failed to delete  emp by id" + error);
      });
  }
}
```

I have a SecurityConfig.java file that looks like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // TODO : use this line when i implement bcrypt
        // auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);

    }

    // TODO : should use this password encoder
    // public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    // return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    // }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // TODO : not secure. Use a different encoder. testing only
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // allow users to access "authenticate" page without being authenticated
        // all other requests must be authenticated
        // stateless tells it to not create a session? Do i need? Not sure yet
        // http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest()
        // .authenticated().and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()).and().csrf()
                .disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // create bean of type 'authenticationManager'
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

I have no clue which function the error is in, but I assume it is the `corsConfigurationSource()` method. However, I see no issue that this shouldn't work. It used to work before I attempted to add security to the app.

AS you can see in that method, I have set all of the allowed methods, I allow all origins, ect, but I still get this error when attempting to delete a user from my database:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees/6151c89ea1b79f789a7a964b' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This DOES work in Postman though. I can Delete a user no problem, it just will not work when triggered from my frontend React app.

It looks like I am allowing everything in `CORS`, any idea what else is left to configure??

[image: ERRORS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `.applyPermitDefaultValues()` call in `SecurityConfig` after instantiating `CorsConfiguration`. This is basically reseting CORS configuration to the defaults:

- Allow all origins with the special value "*" defined in the CORS spec. This is set only if neither origins nor originPatterns are already set.
- Allow "simple" methods GET, HEAD and POST.
- Allow all headers.
- Set max age to 1800 seconds (30 minutes).

Additionally, call `corsConfigurationSource()` method instead of instantiating a new `CorsConfiguration`.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf()
            .disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Also, update your `CorsConfigurationSource` as follows:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better clarity and for the purpose of testing, can you try testing your `corsConfigurationSource()` by the following method.
Please do change the code as it fits to your application such as origin etc.

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

It is basically allowing all headers, methods and origins. It is not ideal for production but for testing purpose you can try this.